# Add pagination to the results in custom module after split the row to many sub rows

Tags: paging

I try to build new module `(Drupal 7)`, in some page I show the results to the user as a table like the following:

```
<?php
    $header = 'bla bla bla'; //header come here
    $query = db_select('myTable', 't')
        ->fields('t', array('field_1', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'due_date'))
        ->extend('TableSort')
        ->extend('PagerDefault');

    $result = $query
        ->limit(10)
        ->orderBy('t.startdate')
        ->execute();

    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $rows[] = array('data' => (array) $row);
    }

    $form['tablesort_table'] = array(
        '#theme' => 'table',
        '#header' => $header,
        '#rows' => $rows,
        '#empty' => t('Sorry, there is no results to show'),
    );
?>
```

and this of course works perfectly (`each page has 10 rows`), but for some reasons I have to split each row to multi sub row according to the `start date` and `end date` like the followin

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $timeInLoop = $row->start_date;
    while($timeInLoop < $row->end_date){
        //split the row to multi row (one week for each row)
        $timeInLoop = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", $timeInLoop) . " +1 week");
        $row->due_date = date("Y-m-d", $timeInLoop);
        $rows[] = array('data' => (array) $row);
    }
}
```

and here is my problem:
if some row has 10 weeks and other row has 2 weeks the total rows in the page will be more than 10 rows 
how can I make them `10 rows in each page` ???
thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/123425/how-would-i-paginate-to-5-results-in-each-page-this-query?rq=1)

```
$limit = 10;
$rows = pager_array_splice($rows, $limit);
$form['tablesort_table'] = array(
    '#theme' => 'table',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#rows' => $rows,
    '#empty' => t('Sorry, there is no results to show'),
);


function pager_array_splice($data, $limit = 10, $element = 0) {
    global $pager_page_array, $pager_total, $pager_total_items;
    $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : '';
    // Convert comma-separated $page to an array, used by other functions.
    $pager_page_array = explode(',', $page);
    // We calculate the total of pages as ceil(items / limit).
    $pager_total_items[$element] = count($data);
    $pager_total[$element] = ceil($pager_total_items[$element] / $limit);
    $pager_page_array[$element] = max(0, min((int)$pager_page_array[$element], ((int)$pager_total[$element]) - 1));
    return array_slice($data, $pager_page_array[$element] * $limit, $limit, TRUE);
}
```